# Install ngx_pagespeed on a existing server

Tags: nginx, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I would like to install [ngx_pagespeed](https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed) on my existing website. Everyone is saying that you need to reinstall nginx completely but unfortunately I can't do that.

**Does anyone know how to do this?**

- nginx version: **1.6.2**

The ngx_pagespeed module url:
https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed

**Thanks in advance!**

EDIT:

I found something about a dynamic module but I don't understand how to use it

> If you would like to build ngx_pagespeed as a dynamic module instead, use --add-dynamic-module= instead of --add-module=. If you build as a dynamic module you also need to tell nginx to load the ngx_pagespeed module by adding this to the top of your main nginx configuration: load_module "modules/ngx_pagespeed.so";

Comment: A compiled module will require you to either compile nginx from source or use another repo which had nginx with pagespeed. You cannot add it to existing setup without changes

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any idea how I can use the dynamic module instead? (I edited the post) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dynamic module also need nginx compile from source using `--dynamic-module` flag. Also you can install nginx on a non-root user. So that would mean you don't need to touch the original installation. See these links http://pjdietz.com/2016/08/28/nginx-in-docker-without-root.html, 
https://www.exratione.com/2014/03/running-nginx-as-a-non-root-user/

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks for your reply!